# How to calculate CRC16 CCITT in PHP HEX?

Tags: php, hex, crc, crc16

I'm trying to use a PHP CRC16 CCITT function to calculate the checksum.

A device sends me a PACKET with Checksum included:

> 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 51 09 08 00 18 00 04 02 14 00 0c 00 0c 02
>   1c 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 77

The checksum is at the end: `a0 77`

I've tried using

[How to calculate crc16 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018508/how-to-calculate-crc16-in-php)

[Convert C to PHP for CRC16 Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078524/convert-c-to-php-for-crc16-function)

With no success, the CRC 16 Calculations return: `E6 F4` instead of  `a0 77`

I get the correct Hex information returned, when I lookup:

> 100000000000000012510908001800040214000c000c021c0002000000000000

on the website http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html but I cannot reproduce it. (make sure to select the input type to HEX)

Can you please help me figure out how to get the crc16 CCITT of the string of hex values

> 100000000000000012510908001800040214000c000c021c0002000000000000

I'm looking for the checksum `a0 77`

Comment: @mpromonet On the website I mentioned: CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) = 0xA077. my apologies for not specifying the CCITT

Comment: FYI, this is actually the "false" CCITT CRC-16.  It is commonly misidentified as the CCITT CRC-16.  However the actual CCITT CRC-16 is reflected with a zero initialization.  See [this catalogue of CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to produce the same checksum with implementation like below:

```
define('CRC16POLYN', 0x1021);

function CRC16Normal($buffer) {
    $result = 0xFFFF;
    if (($length = strlen($buffer)) > 0) {
        for ($offset = 0; $offset < $length; $offset++) {
            $result ^= (ord($buffer[$offset]) << 8);
            for ($bitwise = 0; $bitwise < 8; $bitwise++) {
                if (($result <<= 1) & 0x10000) $result ^= CRC16POLYN;
                $result &= 0xFFFF;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo dechex(CRC16Normal(hex2bin('100000000000000012510908001800040214000c000c021c0002000000000000')));
```

Above gives `a077` on output.

Code snippet found on https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/php-define-function-calculate-crc-16-ccitt.2584389/

Comment: PHP 5.4 is required.. thank you, I wouldn't have known without the link!

Answer (score 2):

I found out from the Deplhi function how it works. It gets an byte Array, instead of Hex string for doing the job.
Here is the code:

```
// $commands = [0x35, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03];       // => 0x5ba3
$commands = [0x44, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x10, 0x03];       // => 0x55c0
var_dump(dechex(getChecksum($commands)));

function getChecksum($byteArray) {
    $polynom = 0x8408;
    $in_crc = 0x0000;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($byteArray); $i++) {
        for ($n = 0; $n < 8; $n++) {
            if((($byteArray[$i] & 0x0001) ^ $in_crc) & 0x0001) 
                $in_crc = ($in_crc >> 1) ^ $polynom;
            else 
                $in_crc = $in_crc >> 1;
            $byteArray[$i] = $byteArray[$i] >> 1;
        }
        $result = $in_crc;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The solution can be proved on [this](https://crccalc.com/) **Online CRC Calculator**.
The Algorithm used is **CRC-16/KERMIT**.

Answer (score 2):

So I was looking for how to calculate checksum according to [ISO/IEC 13239] using the polynomial '1021' (hex) and initial value 'FFFF' (hex). I found this [link](http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/) which can calculate many types of CRC. After submitting my input, I wanted the value of the field `CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF)`, which is something like this:

[image: CRC CCITT 0xFFFF]

So I took the JS function (in the [.js file](http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/js/crcmaster.js), the function name is `CRCFFFF` ) that calculated the CCITT, and created the PHP version of it.

```
function crcChecksum($str) {
    // The PHP version of the JS str.charCodeAt(i)
    function charCodeAt($str, $i) {
        return ord(substr($str, $i, 1));
    }

    $crc = 0xFFFF;
    $strlen = strlen($str);
    for($c = 0; $c < $strlen; $c++) {
        $crc ^= charCodeAt($str, $c) << 8;
        for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            if($crc & 0x8000) {
                $crc = ($crc << 1) ^ 0x1021;
            } else {
                $crc = $crc << 1;
            }
        }
    }
    $hex = $crc & 0xFFFF;
    $hex = dechex($hex);
    $hex = strtoupper($hex);

    return $hex;
}

$result = crcChecksum('replace with your string here');// In my case, this gave me the desired output, which is '627B' (without '0x')
```

In case you need the '0x', just add it:

```
$result = '0x' . crcChecksum('replace with your string here');// result = '0x627B'
```