# How to calculate CRC-CCITT (Kermit) polynomial

Tags: php, crc, kermit

I have a problem with CRC. My message in hex is: **80 00 00 03** an the crc is **f5 1f**. I thought, the polynom is 0x1021 (crc-ccitt kermit). How to find out, what polynom the right one is? And how can I see, if I need it reversed and if the initial value is 0xffff or 0x0000 or something else? How can I calc the polynom I am searching for? Do I have to convert the **80 00 00 03** and the **f5 f1** to BIN and then divide both?
I tried to clac myself with the prog **reveng**, but that was not successful. Maybe because I have not all params -.-

I found a php-function [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035582/how-to-calculate-crc16-ccitt-in-php-hex)

but that will not calc the right sum for me. Maybe it is not CRC-CCITT KERMIT in that php-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x1ff5` is indeed the CRC-CCITT (Kermit) of `80 00 00 03`. (It is apparently stored in little-endian order in your stream.)

The PHP code you found is for the *false* "CRC-CCITT", which you can find in the RevEng catalog [here](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-ccitt-false).

The *true* CRC-CCITT (Kermit) parameters are [here in that catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.kermit). The bits are reversed, so you use the polynomial reversed, `0x8408`, and you shift the bits down instead of up. The initial register contents are zero, and there is no final exclusive-or.

Comment: ah. Do I have to change the polynom from 0x1021 to 0x8408 and the $result from 0xFFFF to 0x0000 in the php-code ? And how can I shift down instead of up ? Sorry, can you help me again ?

Comment: [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) will generate C code for any CRC, including this one.

Comment: can you help me, how to use crcany in console, please??

Comment: mhh, I changed the things in the php-code. but there is always the wrong crc-ccitt (kermit).

Comment: Don't shift up the message byte. Base the `if` statement on the low bit, not the high bit. Use the polynomial reversed. Initialize with zero.

Comment: In the function I changed 
    "$result = 0xffff;" to "$result = 0x0000;"  and 
    "0x1021" to "0x8408" and 
    "if (($result <<= 1) & 0x10000)" to "if (($result <<= 1) & 0x00001)" and
    "$result &= 0xffff;" to "$result &= 0x0000;"

But that is not right I think. Now my checksum is not f5 1f. Can you find the error? Is there something I forgot to change ?

Comment: You are still shifting up. You would need to look at the low bit _before_ shifting down, since it will be lost in the shift down, unlike when shifting up.

Comment: Sorry, thats the part I dont understand :-(

Comment: I can't help you with basic programming.

Comment: Yes, my php-knowledge is very low. Can you help me anyway with the right code, please?

Comment: Pity you can keep your knowledge for yourself :-( If you know the solution, why cant you tell it? :-(

Comment: THX 4 help. Got the solution in php. Works like a charm :-)